# Live code sync for a remote FTP site?

Tags: css, browser, ftp, synchronization, sftp

I develop on a remotely hosted site that I push files to via SFTP.  I would like to set up my site so that I can see any CSS and HTML changes reflected immediately without the need to manually refresh my browser. I've looked at using mixture and browser sync for this but they appear to only work on locally hosted sites.  Any suggestions on how to go about setting this up on remotely hosted project?

Comment: Do you use some IDE for the development that you want to sync the website? Or do basically want live sync of a local folder to a remote one?

Comment: I use PHPStorm and have it setup to upload my changes on change. What I'm looking for is a setup that when my CSS changes get uploaded to the server the browser would suck those changes in without a browser refresh. Similar to the experience you see when coding on jsbin or the like.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try "Emmet LiveStyle", this is a plugin for Chrome and for Sublime Text editor that lets you live code CSS (not HTML) and changes are reflected immediately without the need to refresh the browser. 
Then you can use "Sublime SFTP" package for Sublime Text to automatically upload CSS files on save.
I use this setup and it works perfectly.

Comment: Answers recommending plugins are generally frowned upon by the SO community.